# Quick(est) way to remove all the elements of a vector from another one

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm coding a physical simulation and I'm making great use of two vectors of same elements (homebaked struct). A necessary crucially slowing down my computer is when I'm trying to remove all the elements contained in my vec2 from the vec1 (there could be also many copies of each one of this element in vec2), my current implementation runs with complexity size(vec1)*size(vec2) but it seems like something not to far from sorting algorithm and I'm thinking that someone may have already implemented something much faster (N.log(N)) getting the job done. Have you heard of/manipulated something alike?

Comment: `std::set_difference` should do it.

Comment: ... on sorted vectors.

Comment: @jrok, Yeah, I was just about to add that. It's a possibility, it just depends on whether you can efficiently sort them when needed. Plus you'd have to take into consideration that if `v1` has two 1s and `v2` has one, the result will be one.

Comment: @chris: I'm updated my question, there could be several copies of any vec2 element in my vec1 and I'd like to remove all of them, it seems (from the documentation I read) that set_difference doesn't do that.

Comment: @Liam, Yeah, I noticed. I'm not sure there's an existing algorithm in the C++ STL or in Boost that does this.

Answer (score 0):

If the vectors are not ordered then in any case the complexity will be equal to O( m * n ) where m and n are sizes of the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the vectors by itself is a way slower from what you could achieve if the items are hash-able. It will take (N+M) to create a hash table from one of the vectors, and then search for the items from the other in it.